# MP4 Not Playing Before Fully Loaded on Jwplayer

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, jwplayer

I've searched a lot but couldn't find any solution to the situation i'm in

What i do is i watermark video using ffmpeg.exe via php script but the output file doesn't play on jwplayer.
i've found out that it is an encoding issue and i tried **QTIndexSwapper** but it is for windows.
the input files i used is working nice on jwplayer but after watermark not working
here is the code for ffmpeg i used

```
$ffmpeg_bin -i input.mp4 -s 320x240 -vf 'movie=$watermarkx $watermark_pos' -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict -2 $final_name   2<&1
```

NOTE: i used ffmpeg.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this tool on your file - http://renaun.com/blog/2010/06/qtindexswapper-2/, it has to do with an encoding issue.

Comment: Thanx Ethan yeah i use this tool for windows but for this i need to download a watermark video and than reupload again.i watermarked 15-18 videos daily with 150 mb per file. i want to find a solution which automatically converts watermarked video with correct encoding

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add `-movflags faststart` to your command line:

```
$ffmpeg_bin -i input.mp4 -s 320x240 -vf 'movie=$watermarkx $watermark_pos' -movflags faststart -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict -2 $final_name   2<&1
```

You can also use this option for existing videos without the need to re-encode:

```
$ ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -movflags faststart output.mp4
```

Without this option the index atom (moov) is written at the end of the file and the player can't start playing until it's download / read it. Once encoding finishes this option moves the moov to the beginning of the file and allows the player to start playing immediately. FYI it adds a couples a seconds to the encode process.

Comment: Thanks for answer sir, i added this to my file but video not converted

Answer (score 0):

QTIndexSwapper made my file unplayable.

But you could also try to reencode the file with [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/). Just make sure that you have "[Web optimized](https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/OutputSettings)" checked.